# keyof Foo vs Object.keys(Foo)

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Can anyone explain why this:

```
let foo = new Foo(),
    x: (keyof Foo)[] = Object.keys(foo)
```

leads to:

> Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '"bar" | "bar1"...'

(Using tsc 2.1.4)

Comment: x = <Array<keyof typeof foo>>Object.keys(foo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is due to the fact that `keyof` operator operates in type declaration space whereas `Object.keys` returns you the variable that is from variable declaration space. And you cant simply assign values from different spaces to each other.

More on the matter: [spaces](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html)

Comment: But shouldn't Foo be in the variable space as it is a Class?

Comment: No, as it is class - it is in the declaration space, as it 'declares' the type of the data. On the other hand the instance of the Foo will be in the variable space.

Answer (score 2):

You can type assert it and then it's fine:

```
class Foo {
    x: number;
    y: number;
}

type Keys = keyof Foo;

let foo = new Foo(),
    x = Object.keys(foo) as Keys[];
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20x%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20y%3A%20number%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20Keys%20%3D%20keyof%20Foo%3B%0A%0Alet%20foo%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%2C%0A%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20Object.keys(foo)%20as%20Keys%5B%5D%3B))

The problem is that you are trying to put `string[]` into (in my example) `('x' | 'y')[]` which is more specific.
The same will happen here:

```
interface A {
    x: number;
}

interface B extends A {
    y: number;
}

let a: A = { x: 5 };
let b1: B = a; // error
let b2: B = a as B; // fine
```

When you want to turn something into a more specific type then you need to tell the compiler that you know what you're doing by type asserting it.

Answer (score 0):

The method `Object.keys(...)` returns an array of strings:

```
class Foo {
    public foo: string;
    public bar: string;
}

let foo = new Foo(),
    x: string[] = Object.keys(foo)
```

TypeScript doesn't fully evaluate what the result of `Object.keys` will be in order to guarantee the values will be the right ones... although you can see that they will be compatible in this example...

```
type example = keyof Foo; // "foo", "bar"
```

So your type annotation is correct in your original example, but TypeScript doesn't give such a specific type to the `Object.keys` result.